# CoreBluetooth Central and Peripheral proxmity

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Is it possible for an iPhone to both act as a central and peripheral device broadcasting and receiving to/from other iPhone devices close to the user at the same time. I want something similar to iBeacons but they have limitations such as cannot broadcast in the background and in theory have a maximum limit of devices that can be ranged for. You could say I am looking for a proxmity framework / class written with core BlueTooth.

Just looking for some advice and examples of code, everything online seems out of date.

Comment: You should post your findings with related links, thus to narrow down this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but yes, you can set your device up as a central and periph. You just need to have an instance of `CBCentralManager` to act as the central, and `CBPeripheralManager` to act as the peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

Iphone (4s or later) can be turned to an ibeacon when the app is running in active mode  and you will be able to scan it using the other device which have an app to scan for beacons. In background mode try running the below code with application **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler** I personally never tried this but when app is not in memory transmitting as a beacon will not work.

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"place beacon uuid here"];
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                            major:1
                                                            minor:1
                                                       identifier:@"testBeacon"];
self.beaconPeripheralData = [self.beaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];
self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                 queue:nil
                                                               options:nil];



// Start advertising your beacon's data.
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising: self.beaconPeripheralData];
```

Executing above code will start a beacon and assign your class CBPeripheralManagerDelegate.
Maximum of 20 regions can be monitored by the location manager whereas if you want to scan using core bluetooth than there is no fun of turning them into an ibeacon.